# Pass data attribute to modal in materialize 1.0

Tags: materialize

I would like to use a modal to allow users to edit a record so need to pass the id in when the modal opens.

I found some code for a previous version of materialize (0.98.2) but I can't get it to work for 1.0.

Here is the code that works for 0.98....

```
    $('.modal').modal({
    ready: function(modal, trigger) {
    modal.find('input[name="nom"]').val(trigger.data('nom'))
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like the API has changed significantly in version 1.0. I believe that you can use the [`onOpenStart` or `onOpenEnd` handlers](https://materializecss.com/modals.html#options) instead of the `ready` handler. In addition, the parameters to the `ready` handler used to be jQuery objects, but now they are DOM elements, so your code would need to change to this:

```
$('.modal').modal({
    onOpenStart: function(modal, trigger) {
        $(modal).find('input[name="nom"]').val($(trigger).data('nom'))
    }
});
```